# Proof wanted that there is no positive integer matrix with positive integer eigenvalues u,v,w, if $0<u<v$ and $1\le w-v\le 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following conjecture :

If u,v,w are integers with $0<u<v<w$, then there is a POSITIVE INTEGER 3x3 - matrix A
 with eigenvalues u,v,w if and only if $w-v\ge 3$. I approved the conjecture upto
 w = 9 with brute force.

Is it true that for $w-v\le 2$, there is no solution ?

I found out that the matrix [ [u+1 , v , 1] , [1 , u + v , 1] , [1 , 1 , u + v + 2] ]
 has the eigenvalues u,u+v and u+v+3, therefore the case $w-v=3$ is solved.

I extended the result to the eigenvalues u, u+v and u+v+w+3 to solve the
 case $w-v>3$

[ [ 1 + u , v , 1 ] , [1 , u + v , 1] , [w + 1 , 1 , 2 + u + v + w] ]

So, with the proof for the impossibility in the case $w-v\le 2$, the problem
 would be solved completely.

Comment: The information that you want a matrix with all _positive_ entries is crucial, and must be in the question itself, not hidden away in comments. Please edit the question to make sure all the information is there.

Comment: If u,v are positive integers with u<v then there is a positive integer matrix A with eigenvalues u and v if and only if v-u>1. I did not quite finish the classification if only symmetric matrices are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to find a matrix whose eigenvalues are $u$, $u+v$, and $u+v+w+3$? The straightforward way to do that would be
$$\begin{pmatrix} u & 0 & 0 \\
0 & u+v & 0 \\
0 & 0 & u+v+w+3 \end{pmatrix}$$

If you want something that looks less boring than that, conjugate it with an arbitrary invertible matrix.

If that does not answer your question, you need to express clearer what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Peter: Like this?

Comment: As you can see...

Comment: @ henning Because of my new result I edited my question. Is it now clear enough ?